# Keeping spaces ( or tab ) equal between strings at the same line

Tags: python, python-2.7

How could i improve the following code in order to achieve a decent formatting on the output?

```
import os
print("file\tsomething")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print('{}\t{}'.format(name, 'a'))
```

**Current output**

```
file    something
logging_test.py a
sample.log  a
test.py a
__init__.py a
```

**Desired output**

```
file            something
logging_test.py a
sample.log      a
test.py         a
__init__.py     a
```